# Array Searching and Outputting

Tags: java, arrays

There are two issues that I can not correct from this code.

1. Search for Entree: I'm not sure why it will not allow user input to type into through the console. I am also not sure if the `for` loop for that section is correct. (The user is suppose to search for an entree and it's suppose to print out what day that food is.
2. Highest Price: The only thing wrong with this part of code is that the code always prints out the last food entered regardless of highest price.

Code:

```
String[] daysOfTheWeek = {"Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday"};
String[] foods = new String [5];
double[] prices = new double [5];

//What is being served?

Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

for (int i = 0; i < daysOfTheWeek.length; i++) {
    System.out.println("What entree is being served on " + daysOfTheWeek[i]);
    foods[i] = keyboard.nextLine();
    //Price of items     
}

for (int i = 0; i < foods.length; i++) {
    System.out.println("What is the price on " + foods[i]);
    prices[i] = keyboard.nextDouble();
}

//Search for Entree
String answer;

System.out.println("What food would you like to search for?");
answer = keyboard.nextLine();

for (int i = 0; i < foods.length; i++) {
    if (answer == foods[i])
        System.out.println("This food item will be served on + daysOfTheWeek[i] ");
}

//Highest Price

double highest = prices [0];
int position = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < prices.length; i++) {
    if (prices[i] > highest)
        highest = prices[i];
    position = i;
}
System.out.println("The highest price item was " + foods[position]);
```

Comment: It is not good practice to compare strings with the "==" operator. Instead, use the equals method. if(answer.equals(foods[i])).

Comment: Ok, so show us what your expected output should look like. Also, please give us a narrow idea of where the problem is in your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On your first question: search the internet on how to compare strings in Java (hint: using == is not what you want to do).

On your second question:

```
if(prices[i] > highest)
  highest = prices[i];
  position = i;
```

Try adding braces ;-)

```
if(prices[i] > highest) {
  highest = prices[i];
  position = i;
}
```

Comment: Just a thought - might be worth linking to the Java `if` syntax help page here - https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/if.html  The OP isn't using braces for any `if` blocks, which implies to me they haven't realised the difference between the shorthand version (depends on *rovided that the "then" clause contains only one statement* as per docs) and the version with braces.

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to use braces:

```
if(prices[i] > highest){
    highest = prices[i];
    position = i;
}
```

Also, comparing strings with == compares them by reference: this will return True if and only if it is the same object, not the same value.
Use string1.equals(string2).

Answer (score 2):

I've only taken the relevent parts of your code below.

Here you were comparing strings incorrectly, you should use String.equals(otherString).  You were also not concatinating the daysOfTheWeek[i}, it was included as a string literal.

```
for(int i = 0; i < foods.length; i++)
{
    if (answer.equalsIgnoreCase(foods[i])) {
        System.out.println("This food item will be served on " + daysOfTheWeek[i]);
    }
}
```

Here I have initialised double highest as the absolute lowest value an integer can contain.  You also forgot to wrap you if statement in braces.  If you omit the braces, then only the first line below the if statement/ for loop/ whatever is treated as the body of the statement - wrapping it in braces allows you to enter multiple lines.

```
double highest = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
int position = 0;

for(int i = 0; i < prices.length; i ++)
{
        if(prices[i] > highest) {
            highest = prices[i];
            position = i;
        }

}
```